# Boot Debian Live ISO from grub2

Tags: debian, boot, linux-kernel, grub2, boot-loader

I want to boot Debian buster live ISO from existing Grub2.

Bootable ISO is at `/dev/sdh7` (type: dos, XFS), and
vmlinuz, initrd at "hd7,msdos1" [must be correct, is from actual kernel].

I think I need to specify XFS FS for vmlinuz and initrd.

My actual `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` config:

```
menuentry "Debian Live ISO" {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod loopback
        insmod iso9660
        insmod ext2
        insmod ext4
        set isofile='(hd7,7)/iso/live-image-amd64.hybrid.iso'
        set root='hd7,msdos1'
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.67-custom ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-4.19.67-custom iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet noeject nopromt ro net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initrd.img-4.19.67-custom
}
```

ISO has to be on different partition, cause of low space.
Hopefully there just needs to set XFS filesystem correct!

On the host and ISO system, the same kernel is used.

Error is:

> "hd7 cannot get C/H/S values"

Comment: I am just silly. Best way to deal with that problem is to boot into a grub console, enter "set pager=1" and then "ls" to view all drives.